# osx: Why can't Java read my environment variables?

Tags: java, macos

I have created an environment variable on my mac called "api_url".  I want Java to read that variable and store it as a string.

Why doesn't the code below work?  Notice at the bottom, the output is "null".

[image: Java code with bash shell]

Comment: And just for the record: even when using the correct call `getenv()` you have to make sure that the **process** that runs your IDE has seen that env variable. Exporting it in one shell doesnt make it visible to other, already existing processes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood something here. Properties are [information about the local system and configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-get-property-vs-system-getenv). To access environment variables, you have to use `System.getenv()` instead of `System.getProperty()`.

Try `String url = System.getenv("api_url");`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `System.getProperty`, which is for getting JVM properties - not environment variables. You need to use `System.getenv("api_url")` instead.

[System.getenv(String) docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-)